# css conditional formatting

Tags: html, css

I have the below code to check if the user are using IE7...and it needs to over ride the .web_info style. If not IE7 it uses the default style, if its not IE at all it will use the ff_styles.css. This doesnt seem to be working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">


<![if !IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ff_styles.css">
<![endif]>

<![if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
.web_info
{
left: 450px;
top: 200px;
width: 300px;
height: 60px;   
}
</style>
<![endif]>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional comments are IE specific and therefore "`<![if !IE]>`" is not a valid instruction for firefox or any other browser. Additionally I would suggest you try the following syntax:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
.web_info
{
left: 450px;
top: 200px;
width: 300px;
height: 60px;   
}
</style>    
<![endif]-->
```

One final note on my part: Since IE7/IE8 are mostly standard compliant, these CSS hacks should be avoided, if possible.

**Update:**
Thanks to slosd I stand corrected! According to "[Supporting IE with conditional comments](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/supporting-ie-with-conditional-comments/)" you can use the following to hide something from IE:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
do something; IE will ignore this, other browsers parse it
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Sorry for the inconvenience I caused!

Full working example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">

<!--[if !IE]>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ff_styles.css">
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css">
  .web_info{
    left: 450px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;   
  }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks, so how would I check that it isnt IE...rather than doing if firefox if opera etc

Comment: ! is valid operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

You can use it for styles you want to include in every browser but in IE.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't this look like

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
..
<![endif]-->
```

and

```
<!--[if !IE]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

Note that

```
<!--[if !IE]>
```

should never yield true as these Conditional comments only get interpreted by IE.

Comment: The reason is that, for other browsers, <!-- antything --> appears as an XML/HTML comment and is not interpreted.

Comment: I don't think, what he wants to do is if is NOT IE so if !IE is right

Comment: Thanks but in firefox it still showing the overwritten style not the ff_styles

Answer (score 2):

Don't check if the browser is not IE, check if it is IE7 then if it is IE and then fallback for default.
More info: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html